# Why is nodes=n:ppn=m request not being properly honored by torque/moab?

Tags: linux, cluster, torque

On an inherited cluster that runs torque/moab scheduler, I find that the `nodes:ppn` requests are not properly honored. The nodes are allocated as per the value of `ppn` regardless of the value of `node`. For instance, `nodes=8:ppn=16` will allocate only 4 nodes (each node has 32 cpu cores). I am looking to find possible configuration setting to remedy the situation.